# InstaPy installation error when using python setup.py install

Tags: python-3.x, installation-package

I am currently using Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit) and my pip is version 18.1.

I am following the basic installation steps in GitHub to **install InstaPy but could not finish step 3**:
(https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy#basic-installation)

1. git clone https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy.git
2. cd InstaPy
3. **pip install . or python setup.py install**
4. Download chromedriver for your system from here. Extract the .zip file and

put it in /assets folder.

However, I cannot proceed step 3.

- If I do "pip install", then I will get "'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."
  as I will get "'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command"
- If I do pip install InstaPy with the directory that i have pip.exe, I get "Requirement already satisfied: InstaPy in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.1.dev0)". This is probably because I tried to install InstaPy using "pip install InstaPy" before. (right now, I get error message when i "from instapy import InstaPy" in python)
- if i do "python setup.py install", I will get the following huge bunch of error message.

  ```
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\InstaPy>python setup.py install
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'project_urls'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running install
  running bdist_egg
  running egg_info
  writing instagram_py.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to instagram_py.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to instagram_py.egg-info\requires.txt
  writing top-level names to instagram_py.egg-info\top_level.txt
  file i.py (for module i) not found
  file n.py (for module n) not found
  file s.py (for module s) not found
  file t.py (for module t) not found
  file a.py (for module a) not found
  file p.py (for module p) not found
  file y.py (for module y) not found
  reading manifest file 'instagram_py.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'db'
  writing manifest file 'instagram_py.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
  running install_lib
  running build_py
  file i.py (for module i) not found
  file n.py (for module n) not found
  file s.py (for module s) not found
  file t.py (for module t) not found
  file a.py (for module a) not found
  file p.py (for module p) not found
  file y.py (for module y) not found
  file i.py (for module i) not found
  file n.py (for module n) not found
  file s.py (for module s) not found
  file t.py (for module t) not found
  file a.py (for module a) not found
  file p.py (for module p) not found
  file y.py (for module y) not found
  creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
  creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy
  copying build\lib\instapy\clarifai_util.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy
  copying build\lib\instapy\commenters_util.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy
  copying build\lib\instapy\comment_util.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy
  copying build\lib\instapy\database_engine.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy
  copying build\lib\instapy\feed_util.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy
  copying build\lib\instapy\instapy.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy
  copying build\lib\instapy\like_util.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy
  copying build\lib\instapy\login_util.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy
  copying build\lib\instapy\monkey_patcher.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy
  copying build\lib\instapy\print_log_writer.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy
  copying build\lib\instapy\quota_supervisor.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy
  copying build\lib\instapy\relationship_tools.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy
  copying build\lib\instapy\settings.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy
  copying build\lib\instapy\time_util.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy
  copying build\lib\instapy\unfollow_util.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy
  copying build\lib\instapy\util.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy
  copying build\lib\instapy\__init__.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy
  byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy\clarifai_util.py to clarifai_util.cpython-36.pyc
  byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy\commenters_util.py to commenters_util.cpython-36.pyc
  byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy\comment_util.py to comment_util.cpython-36.pyc
  byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy\database_engine.py to database_engine.cpython-36.pyc
  byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy\feed_util.py to feed_util.cpython-36.pyc
  byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy\instapy.py to instapy.cpython-36.pyc
  byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy\like_util.py to like_util.cpython-36.pyc
  byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy\login_util.py to login_util.cpython-36.pyc
  byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy\monkey_patcher.py to monkey_patcher.cpython-36.pyc
  byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy\print_log_writer.py to print_log_writer.cpython-36.pyc
  byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy\quota_supervisor.py to quota_supervisor.cpython-36.pyc
  byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy\relationship_tools.py to relationship_tools.cpython-36.pyc
  byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy\settings.py to settings.cpython-36.pyc
  byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy\time_util.py to time_util.cpython-36.pyc
  byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy\unfollow_util.py to unfollow_util.cpython-36.pyc
  byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy\util.py to util.cpython-36.pyc
  byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\instapy\__init__.py to __init__.cpython-36.pyc
  creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
  copying instagram_py.egg-info\PKG-INFO -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
  copying instagram_py.egg-info\SOURCES.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
  copying instagram_py.egg-info\dependency_links.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
  copying instagram_py.egg-info\requires.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
  copying instagram_py.egg-info\top_level.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
  zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
  instapy.__pycache__.settings.cpython-36: module references __file__
  creating 'dist\instagram_py-0.0.1-py3.6.egg' and adding 'build\bdist.win-amd64\egg' to it
  removing 'build\bdist.win-amd64\egg' (and everything under it)
  Processing instagram_py-0.0.1-py3.6.egg
  removing 'c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\instagram_py-0.0.1-py3.6.egg' (and everything under it)
  creating c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\instagram_py-0.0.1-py3.6.egg
  Extracting instagram_py-0.0.1-py3.6.egg to c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
  instagram-py 0.0.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

  Installed c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\instagram_py-0.0.1-py3.6.egg
  Processing dependencies for instagram-py==0.0.1
  Searching for grpcio<2,>=1.13.0
  Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/grpcio/
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f3/24/53e18e2c95b46bdb364019e78b96187e263c79166bfee44be9e2554307a4/grpcio-1.16.0rc1.tar.gz#sha256=fc3ae6a062dfc1dee9dae524164bd1bb1f61929b1d3f0727ac889e08b0979702
  Best match: grpcio 1.16.0rc1
  Processing grpcio-1.16.0rc1.tar.gz
  Writing C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-kylgce_3\grpcio-1.16.0rc1\setup.cfg
  Running grpcio-1.16.0rc1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-kylgce_3\grpcio-1.16.0rc1\egg-dist-tmp-aw1tcwnv
  Found cython-generated files...
  warning: no files found matching '*.c' under directory 'src\python\grpcio\grpc'
  warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'src\python\grpcio\grpc'
  warning: no files found matching '*.python' under directory 'src\python\grpcio\grpc'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found under directory 'src\python\grpcio\grpc\_cython'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found under directory 'src\python\grpcio\grpc\_cython'
  warning: no files found matching 'src\python\grpcio\precompiled.py'
  Found cython-generated files...
  cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c++11'
  cygrpc.cpp
  c:\programdata\anaconda3\include\pyconfig.h(119): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
  c:\programdata\anaconda3\include\pyconfig.h(119): note: command-line arguments:  see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
  .\src/core/lib/iomgr/gevent_util.h(43): warning C4267: 'return': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  src\python\grpcio\grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpp(1365): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pthread.h': No such file or directory
  a.c
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 423, in compile
      self.spawn(args)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 542, in spawn
      return super().spawn(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-kylgce_3\grpcio-1.16.0rc1\src\python\grpcio\_spawn_patch.py", line 54, in _commandfile_spawn
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 909, in spawn
      spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\spawn.py", line 38, in spawn
      _spawn_nt(cmd, search_path, dry_run=dry_run)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\spawn.py", line 81, in _spawn_nt
      "command %r failed with exit status %d" % (cmd, rc))
  distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-kylgce_3\grpcio-1.16.0rc1\src\python\grpcio\commands.py", line 301, in build_extensions
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 193, in build_extensions
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 196, in build_extension
      _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 533, in build_extension
      depends=ext.depends)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 425, in compile
      raise CompileError(msg)
  distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 158, in save_modules
      yield saved
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 199, in setup_context
      yield
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 254, in run_setup
      _execfile(setup_script, ns)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 49, in _execfile
      exec(code, globals, locals)
    File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-kylgce_3\grpcio-1.16.0rc1\setup.py", line 348, in <module>
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 169, in run
      cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 155, in call_command
      self.run_command(cmdname)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install_lib.py", line 11, in run
      self.build()
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\install_lib.py", line 107, in build
      self.run_command('build_ext')
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 75, in run
      _build_ext.run(self)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 185, in run
      _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-kylgce_3\grpcio-1.16.0rc1\src\python\grpcio\commands.py", line 306, in build_extensions
  commands.CommandError: Failed `build_ext` step:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 423, in compile
      self.spawn(args)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 542, in spawn
      return super().spawn(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-kylgce_3\grpcio-1.16.0rc1\src\python\grpcio\_spawn_patch.py", line 54, in _commandfile_spawn
      _classic_spawn(self, command)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 909, in spawn
      spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\spawn.py", line 38, in spawn
      _spawn_nt(cmd, search_path, dry_run=dry_run)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\spawn.py", line 81, in _spawn_nt
      "command %r failed with exit status %d" % (cmd, rc))
  distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-kylgce_3\grpcio-1.16.0rc1\src\python\grpcio\commands.py", line 301, in build_extensions
      build_ext.build_ext.build_extensions(self)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 193, in build_extensions
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 196, in build_extension
      _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 533, in build_extension
      depends=ext.depends)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 425, in compile
      raise CompileError(msg)
  distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2


  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "setup.py", line 65, in <module>
      platforms=["win32", "linux", "linux2", "darwin"]
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 67, in run
      self.do_egg_install()
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 117, in do_egg_install
      cmd.run()
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 411, in run
      self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 653, in easy_install
      return self.install_item(None, spec, tmpdir, deps, True)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 700, in install_item
      self.process_distribution(spec, dist, deps)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 745, in process_distribution
      [requirement], self.local_index, self.easy_install
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 863, in resolve
      replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1141, in best_match
      return self.obtain(req, installer)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1153, in obtain
      return installer(requirement)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 672, in easy_install
      return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 698, in install_item
      dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 879, in install_eggs
      return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1118, in build_and_install
      self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1104, in run_setup
      run_setup(setup_script, args)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 257, in run_setup
      raise
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__
      self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 199, in setup_context
      yield
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__
      self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 170, in save_modules
      saved_exc.resume()
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 144, in resume
      type, exc = map(pickle.loads, self._saved)
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'commands'

  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\InstaPy>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but solved it by running:
    pip install .
in the InstaPy folder (the root)